# What is an "unmentionable word" to SQL?

Tags: sql-server, query-store

What is an "unmentionable word" to SQL?

I am reading [sys.query_store_query_text (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and I see the following, so I google {SQL "unmentionable" word}

> has_restricted_text
>   bit
>   Query text contains a password or other unmentionable words.

Other then 3 links that take me back to where I found it, I don't find anything that appears to show a relationship to a password or anything that SQL might care about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is the relationship google found for me, but I don't see how SQL would care enough to track it. I assume it has some other meaning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597519/3789393 possibly related

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596952/restricted-text-when-reviewing-execution-plan-in-sql-server-management-stu

Answer (score 2):

Changing my answer, as I was incorrect in my previous assertion after testing. I believe this is another way of expressing that the value is either a password or another form of ciphertext (encrypted value) instead of a plaintext value.